# Typescript - array to chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array as following:

```
public taskListCustom: any=[
{title: 'Task 1', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 2', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 3', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 4', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 5', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 6', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 7', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 8', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 9', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 10', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 11', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 12', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 13', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 14', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 15', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 16', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 17', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 18', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 19', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 20', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 21', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 22', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 23', status: 'done'},
{title: 'Task 24', status: 'done'},
]
```

And another empty array: `public taskListCustomChunked: any=[];`

My goal is:  if I get chunk size say of 6 (this number can be anywhere between 4 to 11) then I have to chop taskListCustom into 6 arrays (i.e. 24/6=4) and then insert each chunk as an array into taskListCustomChunked i.e. it will look something like:

```
taskListCustomChunked = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[..],[..]]
```

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: if it is 5 then 24/5 how the array should look ?

Comment: the last array can hold less elements if there aren't enough left

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using `slice` method.

```js
let taskListCustom=[ {title: 'Task 1', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 2', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 3', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 4', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 5', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 6', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 7', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 8', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 9', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 10', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 11', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 12', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 13', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 14', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 15', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 16', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 17', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 18', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 19', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 20', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 21', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 22', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 23', status: 'done'}, {title: 'Task 24', status: 'done'}, ]
let chunkLength= 7;
let chunkSize=Math.round(taskListCustom.length/chunkLength);
let result=[];
for (i=0; i<taskListCustom.length; i+=chunkSize) {
    if(result.length<chunkLength-1)
      result.push(taskListCustom.slice(i,i+chunkSize).map(a=>a.title));
    else{
      result.push(taskListCustom.slice(i).map(a=>a.title));
      break;
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi! First of all thanks for your answer :) the only problem is if the chunk size is say 3 then I will have 24 tasks distributed in three arrays which is each of the three arrays in taskListCustomChunked  will have 8 elements and not 3 elements in 8 arrays.